# CSS Background or deprecated HTML bgcolor

Tags: html, css, email, spacing

I am just curious about something.  I am using Litmus.com to do some code analysis on HTML emails. It says that the CSS declaration of "background" isnt supported in a lot of clients.  I am just wondering if its better to stick with what I have or to use the HTML "bgcolor"

Comment: Curious, what is the actual CSS you are trying to use?

Comment: Use `background-color`. Also, when you're coding e-mails, you basically have to treat it as if you are designing a website in the 90s. On that same note, be sure to use inline-CSS. Usually that's a big no-no, but when it comes to e-blasts, it's really the only way to go for maximum compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS like this is supported in email clients:

```
<td align="center" style="background-color: #000000;"> <!-- CONTENT --> </td>
```

CSS3 background properties are not well supported and Outlook does not support background images.

Also, you want to inline as much CSS as you can for full support across browsers.

Take a look at [Campaign Monitors Guide to CSS in Email](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/). It is very useful for seeing what is and is not support in popular email clients.

Answer (score 0):

For the most compatibility use `bgcolor` with a 6-digit hexadecimal color code in combination with the CSS `background-color`. Avoid using 3-digit color codes (e.g. use #ffffff instead of #fff), and also do not use `RGB` or `RGBA` color values.